# Salesforce Rule: if one field populated, then prevent population of the second field

Tags: validation, salesforce, crm

I would like to ask for a help with Salesforce. The official Salesforce communities website encounters a login bug, so I thought I would ask here, as always I got the positive reception here.

I would like to create the rule which will make unable to click the Potential Duplicate field if Left Organization is already marked as True. Could anyone help me to create such rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have found the solution meanwhile. If anyone looks for the answer for similar case this code will help

```
AND(Left_Organization__c=TRUE,Potential_Duplicate__c=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a validation rule that checks in the formula:

`AND (
 NOT( ISBLANK(potential_duplicate_field__c), 
 Left_Organization__c
)`

assuming `potential_duplicate_field__c` is a text or some such and `Left_Organization__c` is a check box.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late response (I was off). Potential duplicate filed is a check box (the same like Left Organization). I tried your code but it returned an error: Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'. Do you know what's wrong?